# cannot use custom view(aar lib) in other project

Tags: android, android-context, aar, custom-view

i have an aar file(i make that) and i want use to another project's application app moudle.

the aar have some custom views

im using android studio

---

**1.Problem**

1) CustomViewLibrary Project

- java sources
- resources (strings, layouts, colors ...)
- *export to aar this project

2) In other SomethingApp Project

- *import the CustomViewLibrary Project's ARR
- typing that some custom view's className to in layout XML

---

**2.Result**

- get NullPointerException in XML Editor(it displayed layout xml preiview 
  tab)
- the exception from CustomViewLibrary Project's AAR(in CustomView class)
- exception message is

  **Rendering Problems**

  java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getColor(Resources_Delegate.java:183)
      at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:915)
      at android.content.Context.getColor(Context.java:508)
      at com.simplier.common.util.ResourceUtils.getColor(ResourceUtils.java:19)
      at com.simplier.common.ui.ActionBar.setTheme(ActionBar.java:245)
      at com.simplier.common.ui.ActionBar.updateUi(ActionBar.java:222)
      at com.simplier.common.ui.ActionBar.(ActionBar.java:69)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

---

i tried rebuild, clear but it not working..

The expected problem is custom view aar access the strange context's resource. (The custom view access colors and others from context(CustomViewLibrary's resources))

sorry for my english..

how can i solve this? please help me

---

### Edit

[in other somthingApp, i want to use my aar to this somthingApp project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oiy8.png)

[the my aar source line when i get NPE, it use aar's resource(in this case colors.xml) from somthingApp's context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIPLa.png)

Comment: add code of class when you receive NPE

Comment: @an_droid_dev i updated my question. please check this images that when i get receive NPE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved

**before**

```
import aar to android studio's menu(File > New > Import Projects > Module ...)
```

**after**

apply the lines to app's build gradle

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
  flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
  }
}
compile(name: 'CustomViewLibrary', ext: 'aar')
```

Now it success to rendering in xml editor AND run